# how to enable/disable specific dates in DateTimePicker winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am programming a `C#` `Windows` application for a clinic and i stored days of works for every doctor for example

Dr.John works every Monday and Tuesday how i can enable dates in `DateTimePicker` for dates that only match the specific days and disable other days .

I don't know what are the methods and functions can help in that

Comment: Show what you try.

Comment: In most cases you are right and the OP should show some effort or share some code to reproduce the problem. But some questions doesn't need code. Maybe the OP wants to to something and they've not found a suitable way to do the job. In such cases instead of posting code or sharing some use-less links, it's better to ask a question straight-forward IMO :)

Comment: Also, there an open source library created by [@Hadi Eskandari](http://stackoverflow.com/users/54538/hadi-eskandari). Here is the link for [codeproject article](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/), [page of the library](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/) in his site and the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Farsi.Library/) package. While the library is called `FarsiLibrary` but its `DateTimePicker` and `MonthView` supports Jalali (Shamsi), Hijri and Gregorian. It enables custom-drawing dates using some rules.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `DateTimePicker` you can

- create a form on the fly
- add a `MonthCalendar` to it
- add either valid or invalid dates to the `BoldDates` collection
- code the `DateChanged` event
- test to see if a valid date was selected
- add it to the list of dates picked

Details depend on what you want: A single date or a range, etc.

Make sure to trim the time portion, mabe like this for adding dates:

```
List<DateTime> bold = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    bold.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i*3).Date);

monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = bold.ToArray();
```

To select only valid dates maybe code like this:

```
List<DateTime> selected = new List<DateTime>();

private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    for   (DateTime dt = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date; 
                    dt.Date <= monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Date; 
                    dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (!monthCalendar1.BoldedDates.Contains(dt)
        && !selected.Contains(dt)) selected.Add(dt.Date);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the options to set any stylings are limited to bolding dates. No colors or other visual clues seem to be possible.

So for anything really nice you will have to build a date picker yourself..