# Set a list of valid dates CalendarDatePicker in UWP

Tags: c#, calendar, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a UWP App with a CalendarDatePicker. When I click in calendar, I make a call to WebService that give me a list of "valid dates". I need, with this "valid dates" list, restrict the calendar in order to the only selectable dates are those, setting the valid dates, or disabling the "invalid dates".

If they can not be disabled it would be enough to mark in some way (bold or crossed out) valid dates (or invalid dates).

I have seen MinDate and MaxDate, but this only allows me set a range, not a list of specific dates.

How I restrict the "valid" dates in a CalendarDatePicker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to enable/disable specific dates in DateTimePicker winforms c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059200/how-to-enable-disable-specific-dates-in-datetimepicker-winforms-c-sharp)

Comment: You can achieve the same in uwp with few changes

Comment: Really I have no idea how achieve the same in uwp: I have no MonthCalendar control and CalendarDatePicker don't have bold collection, and my calendar is already created when I need restrict the CalendarDatePicker... Is not there an easier way to do that?

Comment: @Prabu Winforms and UWP are two completely different APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle this via the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event; there is no MVVM-friendly bindable property to specify the valid dates.

```
<CalendarDatePicker CalendarViewDayItemChanging="onCalendarViewDayItemChanging"/>
```

```
private HashSet<DateTimeOffset> validDates = new HashSet<DateTimeOffset>
{
    DateTimeOffset.Parse("04/01/2017"),
    DateTimeOffset.Parse("05/01/2017"),
    DateTimeOffset.Parse("20/01/2017"),
    DateTimeOffset.Parse("06/02/2017"),
};

private void onCalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.IsBlackout = !validDates.Contains(e.Item.Date.Date);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

As always, you can convert this into an attached property (`ValidDates`, perhaps) or behavior if you want to reuse this functionality.